# Trying to clone a ksh function with little modification with a one liner perl

Tags: perl, sed, lines

I've a short ksh script that is often generated automatically. However, it's missing some stuff and I want to be able to "fix it" like I want by running a simple 1 liner perl to sed it.

Let say that the ksh contains the following function:

```
foo()
{
    /some/command param1
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        /some/other/command stop param1
    fi

    /some/command param2
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        /some/other/command stop param2
    fi

    #...
}
```

and what I really want looks like this

```
foo_force()
{
    /some/command param1
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        /some/other/command stop -f param1
    fi

    /some/command param2
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        /some/other/command stop -f param2
    fi

    #...
}

foo()
{
    /some/command param1
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        /some/other/command stop param1
    fi

    /some/command param2
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        /some/other/command stop param2
    fi

    #...

    foo_force
}
```

So far I've been able to get something "close", ie 2 perl commands, which would be ok with me. However, the second command only replace the last stop by a -f stop... which is not what I'm looking for.

```
/usr/bin/perl -i -pe "BEGIN{undef $/;}; s/^(foo)(\(\)\n{.*\n)}/\1_force\2}\n\n\1\2\t\1_force\n}/gms" /tmp/foo.ksh
/usr/bin/perl -i -pe "BEGIN{undef $/;}; s/^(foo\(\)\n{.* stop)( .*\n})/\1 -f\2/gms" /tmp/foo.ksh
```

Comment: Why not just pass a force argument to foo? then you can just say `foo() && foo(1)`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - you are and evil genius. Although I would pass the word 'force' to make my intent obvious.

Comment: not direct related to your request but why a double `[[` on a `-eq` a single one is enough and faster (no sub process started). On your both comment, use something like foo(force) or foo_force(false). Now your call to foo_force seeems not to be related to failing previus call, is it just unshow code in your sample ?

Comment: Thanks @HunterMcMillen for this idea, I'll try it with something like this at the end of foo()
if [[ -z $1 ]]
then
  foo("-f")
fi

Comment: @NeronLeVelu : thanks for the explanation on [[ vs [. I've always used [[ as I believe it's required when you have multiple condition. Therefore, it's easier to always use [[ even with one condition because it makes it easier to modify to add multiple condition. I'll however consider using [ instead of [[ for the greater cause ;)

Comment: @burgergold: i do it earlier but performance (you create a forked shell instead of work with memory value) and security (audit, ...) are heavily used for this small change. for multi test use simply `&&`or `||` between test. Just be carefull with empty string in test and use double quote for this like `[ -z "${MyVar}" ]`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^foo()/{:a;$!N;/\n}/!ba;h;s/^foo/&_force/;s/stop /&-f /g;s/$/\n/p;g;s/\n}/\n\n    foo_force&/}' /file
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the potential solution but I've forgot to mention I'm on AIX and... without GNU sed. That is pretty much why I've been using perl instead

Answer (score 0):

Using perl

```
perl -0777 -i -pe '
    s{(^foo\(\).*?\n\})}{
        my $foo = my $force = $1;
        $foo =~ s/\}$/    foo_force()\n\}/;
        $force =~ s/^foo\K/_force/;
        $force =~ s/ stop \K/-f /g;
        "$foo\n$force"
    }mse;
  ' /tmp/foo.ksh
```